# How to use Rust regex on bytes (Vec<u8> or &[u8])?

Tags: regex, rust

I have a `&[u8]` and I need to verify if it conforms to some pattern. There are examples of using regexes on `&[u8]` in the [`Regex` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/bytes/struct.Regex.html) and in [the module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/bytes/index.html). I took the code from [the examples section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/bytes/struct.Regex.html#examples) and put it inside a `main()` and added a few declarations:

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"'([^']+)'\s+\((\d{4})\)").unwrap();
    let text = b"Not my favorite movie: 'Citizen Kane' (1941).";
    let caps = re.captures(text).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&caps[1], &b"Citizen Kane"[..]);
    assert_eq!(&caps[2], &b"1941"[..]);
    assert_eq!(&caps[0], &b"'Citizen Kane' (1941)"[..]);
    // You can also access the groups by index using the Index notation.
    // Note that this will panic on an invalid index.
    assert_eq!(&caps[1], b"Citizen Kane");
    assert_eq!(&caps[2], b"1941");
    assert_eq!(&caps[0], b"'Citizen Kane' (1941)");
}
```

I don't understand how this example code differs from regular string matching, and indeed the compiler complains about expecting a `&str`. In general the code does not hint how it differs from the usual string matching, with which I have no problems.

I presume I did something basic wrong, like a missing or more precise import. I am in a guessing game here, as the docs fail to provide working examples (as they regularly do), and this time the compiler also fails to nudge me in the right direction.

Here are the compiler messages:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:28
  |
7 |     let caps = re.captures(text).unwrap();
  |                            ^^^^ expected str, found array of 45 elements
  |
  = note: expected type `&str`
             found type `&[u8; 45]`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8]>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     assert_eq!(&caps[1], &b"Citizen Kane"[..]);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't compare `str` with `[u8]`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8]>` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq<&[u8]>` for `&str`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8]>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     assert_eq!(&caps[2], &b"1941"[..]);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't compare `str` with `[u8]`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8]>` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq<&[u8]>` for `&str`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     assert_eq!(&caps[0], &b"'Citizen Kane' (1941)"[..]);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't compare `str` with `[u8]`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8]>` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq<&[u8]>` for `&str`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8; 12]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     assert_eq!(&caps[1], b"Citizen Kane");
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't compare `str` with `[u8; 12]`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8; 12]>` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq<&[u8; 12]>` for `&str`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8; 4]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     assert_eq!(&caps[2], b"1941");
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't compare `str` with `[u8; 4]`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8; 4]>` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq<&[u8; 4]>` for `&str`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8; 21]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     assert_eq!(&caps[0], b"'Citizen Kane' (1941)");
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't compare `str` with `[u8; 21]`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<[u8; 21]>` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq<&[u8; 21]>` for `&str`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and added a few declarations

Unfortunately, you added the wrong ones. Note how the documentation you've linked to is for the struct **`regex::bytes::Regex`**, not `regex::Regex` — they are two different types!

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::bytes::Regex;
//         ^^^^^

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"'([^']+)'\s+\((\d{4})\)").unwrap();
    let text = b"Not my favorite movie: 'Citizen Kane' (1941).";
    let caps = re.captures(text).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(&caps[1], &b"Citizen Kane"[..]);
    assert_eq!(&caps[2], &b"1941"[..]);
    assert_eq!(&caps[0], &b"'Citizen Kane' (1941)"[..]);

    assert_eq!(&caps[1], b"Citizen Kane");
    assert_eq!(&caps[2], b"1941");
    assert_eq!(&caps[0], b"'Citizen Kane' (1941)");
}
```

> as the docs fail to provide working examples (as they regularly do)

Note that code blocks in documentation are **compiled and executed by default**, so my experience is that it's pretty rare that the examples don't work.

Comment: Thanks. It's the first time I see this "nested import", I thought regex::Regex imported everything in that module. I use both &[u8] and strings so I had to rename the u8 version using "use regex::bytes::Regex as Regex_u8;".

Comment: @user103185 `use regex::Regex` brings in only the type `regex::Regex`. `use regex::*` would bring in all of the types / traits in the `regex` module (non-recursively). You could also say `use regex::bytes; bytes::Regex::new()`, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid that the docs, as a mostly standard feature, omit the "extern" and "use" clauses, so they do not compile. Suggesting that an example is working because all examples are compiled and verified (as I already knew) helps to confuse newbies even more. As modules and imports are critical to using Rust, it would be highly benificial if every sample included these clauses, for daily practice. But when not, at least a link to a page, showing how to compile and run an example, would be highly appreciated. Once a gain thanks for clarifying the import.

Comment: @user103185 at some point there has to be a line drawn; I hope we'd both agree that it would not be reasonable for the documentation to show how to purchase a computer, install an operating system, connect to the internet, install Rust, use the command line, etc. Less obviously, should *every* crate's documentation show how to edit `Cargo.toml`, how to add an `extern crate`, how modules/imports work, what ownership and lifetimes are? I don't believe so, that's why we have [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/), but I can understand why it would cause you frustration.

Comment: @user103185 There is a full example in the README: https://github.com/rust-lang/regex#usage-match-regular-expressions-on-u8 --- If you'd like to submit a PR to add an example to the `bytes` module docs, then that'd be great!